# Changing GeoNode basic zoom?

Tags: geoexplorer, geonode

I'm actually working on GeoNode 2.8 for a company as an internship, one of my mission is to change the basic zoom. They'd like to have a zoom on a specific region instead of having a global view of the map. For this I need to change the zoom level and the position of it but I don't know where to find this function in all these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.py file you have lines for that:

```
# Where should newly created maps be focused?
DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER = (os.environ.get('DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER_X', 0), 
os.environ.get('DEFAULT_MAP_CENTER_Y', 0))

# How tightly zoomed should newly created maps be?
# 0 = entire world;
# maximum zoom is between 12 and 15 (for Google Maps, coverage varies by area)
DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM = int(os.environ.get('DEFAULT_MAP_ZOOM', 0))
```

Edit that code to your location and zoom. Remember that if you are using "local_settings.py" file, this will over-ride your "settings.py".

Answer (score 0):

Have a look in the settings.py file. The parameters for the base map are set there.

It's worth looking at the Django tutorial to see how the application is structured (it's built on Django).

http://docs.geonode.org/en/2.10.x/basic/index.html

https://www.djangoproject.com/start/

Answer (score 0):

As I saw while searching is that no solution has been found to change the zoom, they patched the issues but it still here.